# Is there a way to populate an object instance using AutoFixture?

Tags: autofixture

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do

```
var foo = CreateFoo(); // I don't have access to the internals of CreateFoo

fixture.Populate(foo); // foo should now have random property values
```

Obviously, there is no `Fixture.Populate` method. But how should I solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: You can use an AutoFixture cusomisation, this one is very popular and when you ask autofixture to create an object it will populate the properties with random values... Usually NameOfProperty with a GUID appended.. To use it, just create your IFixture as follows: IFixture fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

Answer (score 3):

AutoFixture indeed doesn't provide API to fill writable properties of an existing object. However, you can use the following snippet to achieve the desired behavior:

```cs
var fixture = new Fixture();
var objectToFill = new TypeWithProperties();

new AutoPropertiesCommand().Execute(objectToFill, new SpecimenContext(fixture));

Assert.NotNull(objectToFill.Value);
```

If you need that often, you can create an extension method for the `IFixture` in your test project.